# Is empty tuple(takewhile()) advancing my iterator in Python?

Tags: python

Python 3.5.4

If I pass a list_iterator to takewhile, then iterate over the takewhile object, the list_iterator is advanced, even when the takewhile object takes nothing. This does not happen when I pass a range object to takewhile. If this is expected behavior, then I've got something to learn.

```
def range_vs_iter():

    # expected works as expected. surprise does not.
    expected = range(5)
    surprise = iter([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])

    # both of these produce an empty tuple
    print(tuple(takewhile(lambda x: False, expected)))
    print(tuple(takewhile(lambda x: False, surprise)))

    # the first element in surprise has disappeared
    print(tuple(expected)) # (0, 1, 2, 3, 4)
    print(tuple(surprise)) #    (1, 2, 3, 4)

    # if I don't iterate over takewhile object, everything is fine
    my_iter = iter([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])
    takewhile(lambda x: False, my_iter)
    print(tuple(my_iter)) # (0, 1, 2, 3, 4)
```

Comment: A range object is not an iterator. It's just an iterable. And yes, of course `takewhile` advances iterators. How is it supposed to get the `x` for your lambda function _without_ advancing the iterator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question can be simplified to:

```
In [9]: expected = range(5)

In [10]: surprise = iter([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])

In [11]: list(expected)
Out[11]: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]

In [12]: list(expected)
Out[12]: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]

In [13]: list(surprise)
Out[13]: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]

In [14]: list(surprise)
Out[14]: []
```

This is because `range` is an object which produces new iterator each time someone calls `__iter__`:

```
In [19]: expected.__iter__() is expected.__iter__()
Out[19]: False
```

However, calling `__iter__` on iterator will always return the same object:

```
In [18]: surprise.__iter__() is surprise.__iter__()
Out[18]: True
```

Which means that you can iterate over iterator object only once